# How to make wireframe transparent in Qt3D?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt3d

I am trying to make wireframe transparent in [one of examples of Qt3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3d-wireframe-example.html), but fails.
I set alpha to 0.5 in robustwireframe.frag, but it does not work.

```
void main(){
// Calculate the color from the phong model
     vec4 color = vec4( adsModel( fs_in.position, normalize( fs_in.normal ) ), 0.5);
     fragColor = shadeLine( color );
```

How to make wireframe transparent in Qt3D?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the QPhongAlphaMaterial https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.11/src/extras/defaults/qphongalphamaterial.cpp and adapt the shader so that it works for your wireframe.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a [BlendEquation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-blendequation.html) to the the renderStates will enable the Alpha blending so add the following code to the RenderPass in the [WireframeEffect.qml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-wireframeeffect-qml.html):

```
RenderPass {
    renderStates: [
           BlendEquation {blendFunction: BlendEquation.Min}
     ]
     shaderProgram: ShaderProgram {
                        vertexShaderCode:loadSource("qrc:/shaders/robustwireframe.vert")
                        geometryShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shaders/robustwireframe.geom")
                        fragmentShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shaders/robustwireframe.frag")
   }
}
```